# Counting numbers in an array that are divisible by any 2 numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, time-limit-exceeded

While solving one question I got stuck with a time limit error. The main objective in question is to count numbers in an array \$A\$ that are either divisible by \$P\$, \$Q\$ or both.

> Input format:
>
> The first line contains a single integer \$N\$ denoting the size of
>   array \$A\$. The next line contains \$N\$ space separated integers,
>   where the \$i\$th integer denotes \$A[i]\$.
>
> The next line contains a single integer \$T\$ denoting the number of
>   queries Monk poses to you. Each of the next \$T\$ lines contains 2
>   space-separated integers \$P\$ and \$Q\$.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> 6
> 2 3 5 7 4 9
> 2
> 4 5
> 3 7
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 2
> 3
> ```

The naive approach from my side is this:

```
a = int(raw_input())                      # Length of an array
b = map(int,raw_input().split())          # Array of size a
c = int(raw_input())                      # Number of query
for _ in xrange(c):                       
    d,e = map(int,raw_input().split())    # 2 numbers
    count = 0
    for i in b:
        if i%d==0:
            count+=1
        elif i%e==0:
            count+=1
    print count
```

I guess it is taking linear time \$O(n) + c\$ which can be improved to \$O(log(n))\$ but I am not sure what's the best way to do it or how to implement it.

Comment: Not giving the link to [the problem statement at hackerearth](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/monk-and-divisor-conundrum/) deprives readers of a piece of information that might be a giveaway: the category is _Integer Factorization & Math Practice Problems_. In performance analysis, in may prove necessary to distinguish _preparation_ and _queries_.